# What is purpose of these files in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have been working with CodeIgniter since 2 years. But I have no idea about following highlighted files.

1. What are them?
2. What happens if I remove them?

[image: Screenshot of Windows explorer with the files .editorconfig, .gitignore, composer.json and contributing.md]

Comment: Do you know what is git? What is composer?

Comment: "I have been working with Codeigniter since 2 years. But I have no idea about following highlighted files." - how it possible to work 2 years as programmer and do not know what is git and composer? o_O

Comment: `.md` files were read me files regarding the framework, `composer` is list of dependencies for the software. `.gitingnore` - files to be not pushed to files repo.

Comment: @Neodan I have worked with git and composer when working with Laravel. But I mean here, what is the purpose for those files to codeigniter? I mean we are not write any commend line commend when working with codeigniter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `.editorconfig` -> [here's the website](http://editorconfig.org/). It's a configuration file to keep settings / code styles for certain IDE's.
2. `.gitignore` is a file used by [git version control system](https://git-scm.com) which tell it which files should be IGNORED by git.
3. `composer.json` is a file used by [Composer dependency manager](https://getcomposer.org/) (for PHP libraries), and that file lists library dependencies, versions, required php extensions and their versions which are needed for the code to run properly.
4. `contributing.md` isn't a special file, it's just a [markdown-formatted file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) that contains instructions left there by the author. You can see that StackOverflow, Github and many other popular programming-related websites use markdown and display it as nicely formatted HTML after parsing.
5. You should really know what GIT and Composer are, so I suggest checking out the links I posted and implementing a bit of google-fu to get up to speed with current tech!

Comment: I have a little bit idea about composer and git because I have worked with Laravel. But why those files here? I mean we are do anything in commond line when working with codeigniter. So what is the purpose for having them in codeigniter....specially composer.jso.

Comment: Without `composer.json` you can't install all dependent libraries that CodeIgniter needs to run. Laravel uses the same thing. I'm a bit surprised that you're not aware of it, seeing that both frameworks heavily depend on open-source libraries which are installed via composer. Those files are there because authors of the frameworks use them, and so do we - the people using those frameworks. I'm not exactly sure what troubles you, those are files that control behavior and manage dependencies of the framework and your application. It's like asking why a car has wheels these days..

Comment: Thanks for the reply... But still I have some questions. You said `you can't install all dependent libraries that CodeIgniter needs to run`. First when we download the Codeigniter from codeigniter.com, it comes with all libraries. Am I correct? So why I had to install install all dependent libraries that CodeIgniter needs to run? I mean even we delete "composer.json" application works fine without any problem.

Comment: Once the dependent libraries are in place, you don't need composer.json any more. I don't know how your project is distributed, but it definitely came with preinstalled dependent libraries so all you had to do is start working.

Comment: Thanks. :-) I just upload all files to server using Filezilla or using Cpanel.

Comment: Nice answer. Vote up.

Answer (score 3):

.editorconfig: This is a file to set coding style in  IDE

.gitignore: This file is for git. You can tell GIT,that certain files are not allowed to be loaded into git.

composer.json: This file is for the libraries in php. It controls the loading and includes all dependencies.

contributing.md: Contains guidelines for contribution, for example, in an open-source project this file plays an important role to provide guidelines for coding standards.

I suggest you keep those files, especially the first three files. DON'T delete them.